# Is neo4j better than mysql

Tags: mysql, neo4j

I am working on a network project and already using mysql as my backend. The project is coded in c++. When my data becomes pretty large, its takes a lot of time to retrieve data from mysql. Hence I was exploring other databases and came across neo4j. After reading a lot of stuff on internet about neo4j and I have few queries. My core requirement of my project is high performance and availability which I am not getting when my database becomes huge.

My questions:

1. I am a little hesitant in using neo4j since I have read on internet at places that it does not perform better than mysql. Is it true?
2. There are no c++ neo4j drivers and can be accessed only via rest apis. Will it make my project even slower as it will be now a http request and response?
3. can we run neo4j on solaris as my server for the project will be solaris?

Comment: totally dependent on your data set; have you profiled your MySQL version the determine why it is "slow?" it's a rare case for rewriting all your database code the be easier than fixing a single performance problem.

Comment: This question (part one, at least) actually doesn't fit on StackOverflow, as it's really an opinion-based question. Regarding part 2 and 3, those seem reasonable and should be posted as individual questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: My answer might be biased since I'm working for Neo Technology. Nevertheless I will stay as objective as possible.

Regarding your questions:

1. It totally depends on your use case if a graph database are a relational database performs better. A graph database excels when you run local queries (e.g. "which are the friends of my friends). By local query I'm referring to a case where you start at one or more bound nodes and then traverse through the graph. For global queries (e.g. "what is the average age of people in the db") a graph database can perform at the same level a relational but will not be  significantly faster. However, if your global queries need to do a lot of traversals, the benefit of a graph database will also be significant.
2. No, using your language's HTTP capabilities will not be slower compared to using a driver. Most of the drivers add some convenience layer(s) for creating the request and parsing the response, and maybe some caching.
3. Neo4j as a JVM based database can run on any JVM 7 enabled platform. However Neo Technology's support offering currently covers Linux, Windows and HP-UX. If you need commercial grade support for Solaris please get in touch with me or my colleagues directly.